# jQuery tablesorter: Prioritize Columns (like in a medal count: First Gold, then Silver, then Bronze)

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm currently working on a alternative medal count for the Olympic Games and use the tablesorter-plugin to give the user the ability to have a look at the data from different angles.

I stick at the point, where it comes to the correct order of the rows: If two nations have the same amount of gold medals, you take a look at the silver medals. The nation with more silver medals gets the first place, the nation with fewer silver medals gets the second place.

How can I achieve this with the help of tablesorter?

You can have a look at the source at http://www.benedictzinke.de/olympia

By now it's sorted after the gold medals per 10 athletes. It's all well sorted for nations which have won at least one gold medal. But the rows of nations without gold medal get messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to hide a weighted medal value in the medal column.

For example, lets look at Korea versus Romania. I've included weighted values in parenthesis which are basically the number of each type of medal including leading zeros (so "2" becomes "002")

```
Country  G (gggsssbbb)  S (sssgggbbb)  B (bbbgggsss)
Korea   12 (012005006)  5 (005012006)  6 (006012005)
Romania  2 (002005002)  5 (005002002)  2 (002012002)
```

Now if we sort the silver medal column, you'll see that Korea's `005012006` is greater than Romania's `005002002` and will sort Korea before Romania.

Now for the code which sets this all up before we even call tablesorter, and a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/106/)

```
$('#medal_count').find('tbody tr').each(function(){
    var pref = '<span style="display:none">', // span that hides the weighted value
        suff = '</span>',
        $t = $(this),
        $c = $t.children(),
        gold = ("000" + $c.eq(4).text()).slice(-3), // add leading zeros
        silver = ("000" + $c.eq(5).text()).slice(-3),
        bronze = ("000" + $c.eq(6).text()).slice(-3);
    // add hidden weighted medal values
    $c.eq(4).prepend(pref + gold + silver + bronze + suff);
    $c.eq(5).prepend(pref + silver + gold + bronze + suff);
    $c.eq(6).prepend(pref + bronze + gold + silver + suff);
});

$("#medal_count").tablesorter({
    textExtraction : function(node){
        var $n = $(node);
        // only return the weighted values if a span exists
        return ($n.find('span').length) ? 
            $n.find('span').text() :
            $n.text();
    },
    sortList: [[8, 1]]
});
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your response. Both answers were very useful. 

hradac: I'll definitly have a look at the custom parsing stuff for later projects, but I think it will not help in this special case, because the values are already numeric and therefore sortable with the built-in parser.

fudgey: Thanks for this approach and your comprehensive explanation. Looks like an easy-to-implement-way. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks again, I finally had some time to implement the "weight" span. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tablesorter plugin you should reference the documents about writing your own parser. See it here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

What you're asking for seems to fit almost exactly to the example used in the documents. For convenience the code from the docs is copied below.

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'grades', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toLowerCase().replace(/good/,2).replace(/medium/,1).replace(/bad/,0); 
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { 
                sorter:'grades' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

For your purposes the code would look like this:

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'medals', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        // Note the 'i' added after the medal type, that makes it case insensitive.
        return s.toLowerCase().replace(/gold/i,2).replace(/silver/i,1).replace(/bronze/i,0); 
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: {  // Replace '6' with the number of the column that your medals are in
                sorter:'medals' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```